# Java code to handle node failure in jgroups cluster

Tags: java, cluster-computing, jgroups

My Jgroups config file contains the protocol/config

```
<FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
```

But how do I use this in the Java code. For example, if there is a cluster and when I detect a failure I want to call an external notifier service via a REST call, `like /nodeDown/nodeID` 
I'm not able to find any java code which does this, all I see is message receive and send, is there a way I can implement this?

Thanks

Adding some more info
I have done the step of writing a RecieverAdpater and override the start, stop, send, recieve method. Please find some code here,

```
public void receive(Message msg) {
    JGroupsDataPacket pckt = (JGroupsDataPacket) msg.getObject();
    if ( pckt.getCmd().equals("cacheUpdate") ){
        int uid = pckt.getAffectedUid();
        cacheUpdateRoutine(uid);
    }
    if ( pckt.getCmd().equals("ack") ){
        System.out.println("got the mesaage!");
    }       
    logger.log(LogLevel.ERROR, "received msg from " + msg.getSrc() + ": " + msg.getObject());
}

public void send(JGroupsDataPacket pckt){
    Message msg = new Message(null, null, pckt);
    msg.setFlag(Message.Flag.RSVP);

    try {
        channel.send(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to know where should `I add code for example to handle the TimeOutException when I'm sending a message with the RSVP flag enabled.` Another requirement is to know, `which is the Java callback method which is called when SUSPECT(P) is triggered.` I want to catch and handle the machine's going down, timout etc.

```
Is the viewAccepted() the only place where I can handle this? Is there a sample code around this?
```

Also is http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/user-channel.html
the section 3. APIs give all java/programmatic things we can do with JGroups.

Thanks again

I found some documentation here, I think this is the class which I'm supposed to override

```
public interface MembershipListener {
    void viewAccepted(View new_view);
    void suspect(Object suspected_mbr);
    void block();
    void unblock();
}
```

Comment: First off, RSVP throws a TimeoutException which is a RuntimeException, so you need to wrap JChannel.send() in a try-catch clause.  Second, the manual you're looking at is old; the new one is here: http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html.  Third, suspect events should not be handled, as they are only an *indication* that some member crashed. They're double checked, and evantually a view is emitted, so the view is what you should deal with.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first off, you have a JChannel. You need to use it to register for view callbacks, like this:

```
   JChannel ch;
   ch.setReceiver(this);
```

'`this`' *extends* `ReceiverAdapter` and *overrides* `viewAccepted()`:

```
   public void viewAccepted(View view) {
       // handle new view
   }
```

To determine the members which left between views v1 and v2:

```
   List<Address> left_mbrs=View.leftMembers(v1,v2);
```

Comment: Hi @BelaBan thanks for your comments, I saw some code in the workshop repository, some slides and some code. I have added some more information to my question above, to help solve this doubt easier thanks!